# Email in AspNetUsers table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using yahoo OAuth to authenticate the users. I am getting logged in using yahoo credentials as well.

Screen of AspNetUsers table where I can get only the User Name of the Logged in user.

[image]

But I am not able to get the Email id of the user in Email column of the table. Is there any another table or process by which I can get the Email Id of the users.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the Email using following steps:

1) Add the Textbox in 'RegisterExternalLogin.aspx' so that the user can enter the email id after successful login via Yahoo.
[redirected page after yahoo login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbZ2Q.png)

2) Add the following piece of code in 'RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.cs' so that the entered email id will be inserted into the Email column of a AspNetUsers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GCch.png)

After this much of addition in the code, the textbox data will be inserted into the AspNetUsers table.